# 0 variables? how can i fix it

Tags: r

Objective: I would like to have a sub dataset  that shows all observation related to women between the ages 18-19,20-24,25-34 (already codified in 7,8,9) and to have this i entered the following:

```r
women <- AVQ19[AVQ19$SEX == 2, AVQ19$AGE >= 7 & AVQ19$AGE <= 9,]
```

however, when i run the code it shows:

```
23527 obs. of 0 variables (the dataset has overall 45483 obs of 26 variables)
```

Comment: The `,` is not clear,  Should that be `&` or `|` i.e. `AVQ19[AVQ19$SEX == 2|AVQ19$AGE >= 7 & AVQ19$AGE <= 9,]`

Comment: Replace the comma in your code above after SEX == 2 by an &

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `,` in your subsetting should likely be a logical (`&` or `|`).

Options:

```r
women <- AVQ19[AVQ19$SEX == 2 & AVQ19$AGE >= 7 & AVQ19$AGE <= 9,]
women <- subset(AVQ19, SEX == 2 & AGE >= 7 & AGE <= 9)
women <- dplyr::filter(AVQ19, SEX == 2, AGE >= 7, AGE <= 9)
```

I included the `dplyr::filter` above to demonstrate why it might seem that the comma would make sense elsewhere. Within `dplyr::filter`, all arguments (after the data argument) are `&`'ed together. One can always use explicit `&` here as well in place of the commas,

```r
women <- dplyr::filter(AVQ19, SEX == 2 & AGE >= 7 & AGE <= 9)
```

for precisely identical results. I suspect the rationale for allowing commas, is that it allows for more fluid (perhaps more readable) line-based line-wrapping, such as

```r
... %>%
  filter(
    SEX == 2,
    AGE >= 7,
    AGE <= 9
  )
```

I'm not espousing that you switch to `dplyr` solely for this benefit (though there may be benefits to learning `dplyr`, for other reasons). I just thought if you had seen the comma in this use, know that outside of `dplyr::filter`, comma-separated logicals do not necessarily mean the same thing.

---

FYI, the reason it is returning `23527 obs. of 0 variables` is because the second argument after your comma is taken as a column-index. I'm going to assume that your `df` has many more rows than columns, and `AVQ$AGE >= 7 & AVQ$AGE <= 9` likely returns numbers much higher than the number of columns you have.

The `23527` is likely the number of rows of `AVQ` where `SEX == 2` is true. The `0 variables` is likely because none of them occur in the first few rows, i.e., the first occurrence of `AGE` between 7 and 9 is on a row number that is greater than `ncol(df)`.